# vector::erase() not working

Tags: c++, vector

RemoveContact_HI have created this function to remove an element in a vector:

```
void JNP::IPComm_HostType::RemoveContact_H( UINT contactIndex,std::vector<IPContact>& l )
{
    assert( contactIndex < l.size() );
    l.erase( l.begin() + contactIndex );
}
```

However it does not appear to work. The element is not removed when I call the function. The size of the vector is reduced by 1, but you can still access all all the elements including the deleted element by coding

```
hostList[some integer]
```

I.e if hostList had 2 elements and I were to call

```
RemoveContact_H( 0, hostList )
```

the size would be reduced to 1, but both elements would still exits and could be accessed!

**EDIT**

Unsurprisingly, the error was due to my coding and not the vector::erase() function. I had previously defined the equals operator for the IPContact class which didn't actually copy any data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [*Undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to access elements already erased from a vector. Sometimes it will work (your case) but it will crash at the worst moment possible (i.e. during the demos, or in front of your family ;) ).

But if you use [`std::vector::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) to access the element already erased, it will throw a [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception.

The [`std::vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) does not perform a **bounds checking**.

> the size would be reduced to 1, but both elements would still exits and could be accessed!

Like I said before, it is *Undefined Behavior* and you should not try to access erased elements. Try to do it with `vector::at`, it will throw an exception.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, but it still doesn't answer the question. If I have two elements in a vector, I call erase to element of index 0, then index 1 should then be re-assigned to index 0 surely?
If I then call vector::at(0), it still returns the element of index 1 which should have been removed by the last call?

Answer (score 3):

> the size would be reduced to 1, but both elements would still exits and could be accessed!

**No**. If your vector's size is 1 then only one element exists (index 0) and only this element can be accessed. Trying to access elements beyond that is Undefined Behaviour and as such it may crash your program or it may *appear* to work, who knows, but in the latter case that doesn't make your code any more correct.

In other words, `std::vector::erase()` is behaving as it should, it's just that you're not using `std::vector` as you should (ie. you must never try to access an element past the end).

You might want to use `std::vector::at()` instead of `std::vector::operator []()` in order to verify by yourself that only index 0 is accessible.